# Adding bullet instead of numbers in toc in subsubsection

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, bullets

How can i use bullets instead of numbers in TableOfContents in subsubsection parts? The solution must simillar to this [Numbers and bullets in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170478/numbers-and-bullets-in-table-of-contents#new-answer) one i guess, but i am new to latex and could not figure it out by myself. Image shows, what happens if i just replace \l@paragraph by \l@subsubsection
[image: This happens if i just replace \l@paragraph by \l@subsubsection]

Comment: Using the answer you linked, you simply have to replace `\l@paragraph` by `\l@subsubsection`.

Comment: @Jojo i have tried to do this many times, but all i get is that one on the image

Comment: Hello! It's would be _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a _complete_ and _self contained_ example. It means that if we can copy paste the code, it would run _and_ your problem would reveal it self! i.e. it should include a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking.

Comment: Do you only want bullets in the TOC, or in \subsection as well?  The latter is an easier fix since it only involves \thesubsection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the linked solution as an MWE.  Note that `\l@subsection` is document class dependent.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[1]{%
  \@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{1em}{%
    \numberline{\textbullet}%
    \gobble@numberline
    #1%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\gobble@numberline}{%
  \@ifnextchar\numberline{\@gobbletwo}{}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\lipsum}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.%
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \newpage
  \section{First section}
  \subsection{First subsection}
  \subsection{Second subsection}
  \subsection{Third subsection}
  \section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]